# How to find the OS of the target machine

Tags: operating-systems, network-scanners, detection, nmap, os-fingerprinting

I am new to this field. Currently I am using Linux OS and 
my question is how can I find the OS of another machine to
which I do not have a direct access.

I am interested in any possibilities which can lead me to 
this information.

Also I need to detect the OS precisely.

I used nmap -O  before.

Comment: Do research about OS footprinting.

Comment: If that machine is server then you could try nmap of port 25 to check whether the machine is running with which Mail server if its Exchange then its sure windows machine others might have linux distros.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you can send packets to the target machine, use nmap -O, which provides OS fingerprinting.

If you can eavesdrop/intercept network traffic with the target machine, use [pof](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/), a tool for passive OS fingerprinting.

You didn't provide much information about what are your constraints or why the standard tools (like nmap or pof) didn't work for you.  Therefore, I'll provide some generic advice: I suggest you look into [OS fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting).

Answer (score 5):

Go throughout this article about remote OS foot printing.
http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't alway work, but you can simply look at the headers that a webserver sends (notice the `<=========<<<<` below). None of the answers will get you 100% assurance, but combining methods will improve your results:

```
$ wget -SO /dev/null 'http://microsoft.com/'
--2012-12-31 15:27:27--  http://microsoft.com/
Resolving microsoft.com (microsoft.com)... 64.4.11.37, 65.55.58.201
Connecting to microsoft.com (microsoft.com)|64.4.11.37|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Length: 23
  Content-Type: text/html
  Location: http://www.microsoft.com
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 <=========<<<<
  Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSASTCBRC=LHFJPMCBKJFJNIBMEKIALFIC; path=/
  P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
  Date: Mon, 31 Dec 2012 14:27:29 GMT
  Connection: close
```

`wget` retrieves a document from a webserver. `-S` prints out the headers. `-O /dev/null` redirects output to /dev/null. In this case you're only interested in headers, not the document.